# const reference to static member

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, static, member

```
struct Foo
{
    constexpr static int n = 10;
};

void f(const int &x) {}

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    f(Foo::n);
    return 0;
}
```

I get error: main.cpp|11|undefined reference to `Foo::n'|. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler error is required by the standard. Since your function

```
void f(const int& x)
```

takes it argument by reference, in the call

```
f(Foo::n);
```

the variable `Foo::n` is *odr-used*. Hence a **definition** is required.

There are 2 solutions.

1 Define `Foo::n`:

```
struct Foo    
{   
    constexpr static int n = 10; // only a declaration    
};    

constexpr int Foo::n; // definition
```

2 Take the argument of `f` by value:

```
void f(int x);
```

Comment: @Yivo why would we need to pass the static member as reference? is it not useful only if the class and the free function are in different scopes and we operate on them? or is it useful any other ways? not able to think of possible use cases so..

Comment: Third solution, if Foo is a template class and you can't change `f`: use `f(+Foo::n)` instead.

Answer (score 2):

What compiler version do you use? It seems, it has some issues with C++11 dialect (ideone.com compiled that with 100% success).

Maybe, it's a good idea to try this instead?

```
struct Foo
{
    static int n;
};
int Foo::n = 10;
```

Comment: I am using MinGW GCC 4.7.3. I will update the compiler to the latest version (4.8.1) and report the results. Thank you.

Comment: This seems to be a bug in GCC 4.8. OP’s code should *not* compile as far as I understand, and MWid’s answer shows why.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Technically, this code can compile but not link. For odr-use of a static data member, which is not defined, the standard explicitely states "no diagnostic required" (see §9.4.2/4).

Comment: @MWid Ah yes, of course – this obviously makes sense since the compiler *cannot* diagnose this. But when I said “compile” I actually colloquially meant the whole process, including linking.